# Power BI - Show hierarchical/grouping data

Tags: powerbi

I'm looking to see if it's possible in Power BI to have a widget that shows "common" data in one row, then "differentiating" data below it in other rows.

For example, let's say I want to show a list of TV shows. And below each TV show, I want to show data about each season. So data might look like (I'm not filling out all of the data, just enough to show an example):

| TV Show Title | Broadcaster | Genre | Season # | Season Premiere Episode Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mad Men | AMC | Period Drama | 1 | Smoke Gets in Your Eyes |
| Mad Men | AMC | Period Drama | 2 | For Those Who Think Young |
| Game of Thrones | HBO | Fantasy | 1 | Winter is Coming |
| Game of Thrones | HBO | Fantasy | 2 | The North Remembers |

I want to show the data that looks kind of like this:

|  | TV Show Title | Broadcaster | Genre | Season # | Season Premiere Episode Title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| +/- | Mad Men | AMC | Period Drama |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 1 | Smoke Gets in Your Eyes |
|  |  |  |  | 2 | For Those Who Think Young |
| +/- | Game of Thrones | HBO | Fantasy |  |  |
|  |  |  |  | 1 | Winter is Coming |
|  |  |  |  | 2 | The North Remembers |

At first I thought I could use a matrix, but it doesn't seem to work that way I hoped.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

[image]

If so, turn stepped layout off in the options.

[image]

My data looks like this

[image]

[image]

Comment: Kind of. But I don't want to force users to expand the columns for each row of data they want to see the common data for (and ideally, not show the expand/collapse at all for those).

I also tried putting stuff like Genre and Broadcaster into Values, but that doesn't do exactly what I want either.

Comment: You can pre-expand all columns and you can remove the +/- buttons. It is highly configurable.

Comment: Hmm, where do you do that? So I would only show the first +/- button and pre-expand everything else.

Comment: Under row headers (+/- icons). You either turn them off for everything or on for everything.

Comment: Yeah ideally I would be able to keep one that controls whether to show the differentiating data or not. Also, where do you pre-expand the columns?

Comment: You just click the +/- icons to expand and they will remain expanded for your report users.

Comment: Yeah but that means I have to expand each individual column for each row. The data I have above is just an example to show what I'm looking to do. In reality, there will be more columns, more rows, and the data will refresh. So this isn't practical.

Comment: You can right click and expand all...

Comment: Yeah, between not being able to show only one +/- button to expand/collapse everything and having to insert rows with blank data, this isn't ideal. One of the visuals in the Power BI visuals might do it, but it's a paid one.

Comment: That's PowerBI I'm afraid. You can raise a ticket with MS or suggest an idea to them.